# PHP - remove last part of string - preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to remove `"from  products where id = 153183"`.  The id can change and so I need to use a preg_replace to remove everything after the word "from" and then possibly use str_replace to remove from.  I have the below but this will only remove the word from if its last in a string.  Can anyone suggest what I need to add?

```
//doesn't work

$str = "select id, productdescription, category, price, code, manufacturer, categoryid from  products where id = 153183";

$new_str = preg_replace('/from$/', '', $str);
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to remove `FROM` clause, not `WHERE` only?

Comment: There's not need for a regular expression. Especially when matching on a simple string.

Comment: yes I'm sure what I want to remove from he string.  I don't know what he ID will be in the string therefore how can I do it without a reg ex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like `/from.*$/` or simply `/from.*/`

Comment: If the word `from` is present multiple times you will be in trouble though.

Comment: What about a statement like "SELECT roads_from_rome FROM maps"? `\bfrom\b` or `\sfrom\s` should help with that.

Comment: @Blazemonger: Yeyeye, but OP isn't going to solve that one using a regexp. He'd need a proper query parser. :-)

Comment: `.*?` is the not greedy version

Comment: Not sure what you mean by greedy but the first one works thanks. 'from' will only be in there the once. BTW - Im a she not a he @Denis ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

```
$new_str = stristr($str, " from ", true);
```

As *from* is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in SQL you can't find this word elsewhere without quote or backtick (so I add a space after and before).

It returns the string before the "from" word.

`strstr` *for a case-sensitive search.*

UPDATE: Regular expression (not really needed for this question) :

```
$str = 'select id, productdescription, category, price, code, manufacturer, categoryid from  products where id = 153183';

preg_match('/(.*)\sfrom\s.*$/i', $str, $matches); // i for the insensitive case search

$new_str = $matches[1]; // Contains what you want
```

Comment: + for a non-regular expression solution.

Comment: Wouldn't [`stristr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) be a better choice?

Comment: Now we just need to consider the possibility of, say, newline characters around `FROM` instead of plain spaces.

Comment: Use regex for more complex search operation.

Comment: @Blazemonger: or of `select foo_from from bar`... :-)

Comment: @Denis, yes I know, but the response is suited to the question. For a more complex answer, regex is needed

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by your question, this should get you going though.

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = 153183';
$sql = preg_replace('~from products where id = [0-9]+$~i', '', $sql);
echo $sql;
/*
    SELECT * 
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple `str_replace`. Not sure how you are getting the id since it can change, I am assuming you have a variable for it.

```
$str = "select id, productdescription, category, price, code, manufacturer, categoryid from  products where id = 153183";
$new_str = str_replace("from products where id = " . $id, "", $str)
```

Comment: The value of `id` can change.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "select id, productdescription, category, price, code, manufacturer, categoryid from  products where id = 153183";
$part1 = substr("$string",0, strrpos($string,'from  products where id '));
var_dump($part1);
```

Since the bulk of the string is static you can use a sub string up to the offending section.

RESULTS:

```
string(79) "select id, productdescription, category, price, code, manufacturer, categoryid "
```

Answer (score 0):

Combination of `preg_replace` and `str_replace` will also work:

```
<?php

$str = "select id, productdescription, category, price, code, manufacturer, categoryid from  products where id = 153183";
$id_removed =  preg_replace('/\d/', '', $str); //remove dynamic product id
$new_str = str_replace("from  products where id =",'', $id_removed);
echo $new_str;


?>
```